# No pip version for python3.7?

Tags: pip, python-3.7

I have installed python3.7 on my mac and Ubuntu 18.04. but there does not seem to be a new pip to install modules for python 3.7.

Whats up? When will I be able to install a 3.7 version of pip?

Comment: `python3.7 -m pip`?

Comment: What do you mean, a new pip? Python is, in general, forwards compatible. No new pip should be necessary just because there was a version upgrade. You should be able to install the current pip no problem.

Comment: The answer from hoefling worked great.  In answer to your question, if you use the pip command from the command line, it makes modules available for only one version of python, if you have multiple versions on your computer, you must choose specific commands pip, pip3, or pip3.6 to for where pip will install the module. My problem was geting pip to make modules available for python3.7., and I did not know you could invoke pip with the -m flag from python before.

Answer (score 9):

yup..

- You can download get-pip from **https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py**
- After download file run as,
- `ashutosh@ashutosh:~/Downloads$ sudo python3.7 get-pip.py`
- it will install current pip on your system